# Acer Aspire R11 Series 3 forgotten administrator password

Tags: administrator, password-recovery, reset

I am trying to factory reset my acer aspire but it is having problems resetting so I need to do a system restore or command prompt but in order to use those I have to have the administrator password which I have forgot

Answer (score -1):

I will not be original. You can make a bootable usb stick with linux and reset or remove the password from Windows. You can use rufus or balena etcher and any Linux iso image. For example Fedora, because it has an option to run live instead installing it. In live then you must do some steps to remove password from Windows. See this link. https://opensource.com/article/18/3/how-reset-windows-password-linux

Comment: Automated minus? LOL. For a God sake! Super User is really full of bunch of idiots. Because you are not able to use Linux it does not mean you should minus the answer which is correct. Damn! Shame on you and go to psychologist to cure your problems.